# Exception Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, spring.net

Sometime i m getting this problem in my NHibernate log .My application stops at that moment.

Updated wityh data configuration.

Even after successful transaction.Application connection with the database persist.in

Nhibernate log it shows

Nhibernate Log

> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl
>   [(null)] <(null)> -
>
> executing flush
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG
>   NHibernate.Impl.ConnectionManager [(null)] <
>
> (null)> - registering flush begin
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG
>   NHibernate.Impl.ConnectionManager [(null)] <
>
> (null)> - registering flush end
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl
>   [(null)] <(null)> -
>
> post flush
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl
>   [(null)] <(null)> -
>
> before transaction completion
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG
>   NHibernate.Impl.ConnectionManager [(null)] <
>
> (null)> - aggressively releasing database connection
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG
>   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider
>
> [(null)] <(null)> - Closing connection
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl
>   [(null)] <(null)> -
>
> transaction completion
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG
>   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction [(null)] <
>
> (null)> - running AdoTransaction.Dispose()
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl
>   [(null)] <(null)> -
>
> closing session
>
> 2010-05-21 14:45:08,428 [Worker] [0] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.BatcherImpl
>   [(null)] <(null)> -
>
> running BatcherImpl.Dispose(true)

Underneath given is my dataconfiguration file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<objects 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" 

         xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"

     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.net/tx">

  <object id="AuditLogger" type="Risco.Rsp.Ac.Audit.AuditLogger, Risco.Rsp.Ac.Audit" singleton="false"> 

    <property name="CacheSettings" ref="CacheSettings"  />
  </object>


  <object id="CacheSettings"

          type="Risco.Rsp.Ac.AMAC.CacheMgmt.Utilities.UpdateEntityCacheHelper, 

Risco.Rsp.Ac.AMAC.CacheMgmt.Utilities" singleton="false"/>

  <!-- Property placeholder configurer for database settings-->

  <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">

    <property name="ConfigSections" value="databaseSettings"/>
  </object>

  <db:provider id="AMACDbProvider"

                provider="OracleClient-2.0"

    connectionString="Data Source=RISCODEVDB;User ID=amacdevuser; Password=amacuser1234;"/>

  <!-- For creating Factory objects -->
  <object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" 

  type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject,Spring.Data.NHibernate12">

    <property name="DbProvider" ref="AMACDbProvider"/>

    <property name="MappingAssemblies">
      <list>
              <value>
    Risco.Rsp.Ac.AMAC.CacheMappings

       </value>

      </list>

    </property>

    <property name="HibernateProperties">

      <dictionary>

        <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider"

               value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"
         />

        <entry key="hibernate.dialect"

               value="NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect"
              />


        <entry key="hibernate.connection.driver_class"


               value="NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver"/>

      </dictionary>


    </property>

  </object>


  <object id="HibernateTemplate" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTemplate"

singleton="false">

    <property name="SessionFactory"

 ref="NHibernateSessionFactory" />

    <property name="TemplateFlushMode" 
value="Auto" />

    <property name="CacheQueries" value="true" />

    <property name="EntityInterceptor" ref="AuditLogger"/>

  </object>


  ><object id="transactionManager" singleton="true"  

    type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, >Spring.Data.NHibernate12">  

    <property name="DbProvider" ref="AMACDbProvider"/>

    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>

    <property name="EntityInterceptor" ref="AuditLogger"/>

  </object>


  <object id="EventPubSubDAOTx" 

type="Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryObject,Spring.Data">

    <property name="PlatformTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>

    <property name="Target" ref="EventPubSubDAO"/>

    <property name="TransactionAttributes">
       <name-values>

        <add key="Save*" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"/>

        <add key="Delete*" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>

      </name-values>

    </property>

  </object>


  <object id="EventPubSubDAO"  

    type="Risco.Rsp.Ac.AMAC.DAO.EventPubSubMgmt.EventPubSubDAO, 

   Risco.Rsp.Ac.AMAC.DAO.EventPubSubMgmt">

    <property name="HibernateTemplate" ref="HibernateTemplate" />

    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>

  </object>

  <!-- EventPubSubMgmt DAO -->


  <tx:attribute-driven/>

  </objects>
```

Please help me out with this issue.Thanks

Comment: wait, the crystal ball is clearing...

Answer (score 0):

The exception is often caused by **using a session which is already closed**. Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902144/application-not-releasing-database-connection-spring-net-nhibernate) also points to the fact that you may have to reconsider your connection and session usage.

Because there is not much information in your questions, it is hard to suggest an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for reply jan .Can u please provide me ur mail id,so that i can send u DataConfiguration and some more logs

Comment: I'd rather not. That's what this site is for, and my time is not free. You should do some research yourself, try to isolate the problem, and post the results on this site. If you invest some time to find out what the problem is, and take some time to describe the problem properly, there are a lot of people on StackOverflow willing to help you.

Comment: Man i reasearch a lot,thn only has come up with .Event i would like to help people in stack overflow,I had just asked u for that .Because it will be more convinient for u.Later we would have published it.Thanks for your reply